# Stuck in while loop when change to c++

Tags: c++, performance, cryptography

i'm trying to rewrite this code in c++ which create a bitcoin mini private key

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;


 public string CreateRandomMinikey(){
        string keytotry = "S6c56bnXQiBjk9mqSYE7ykVQ7NzrQA";
        char[] chars = keytotry.ToCharArray();
        char[] charstest = (keytotry + "?").ToCharArray();            
        while (Util.ComputeSha256(utf8.GetBytes(charstest))[0] != 0) {// hash sha256 the key & check if the first character was '0'
                // As long as key doesn't pass typo check, increment it.
                for (int i = chars.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    char c = chars[i];
                    if (c == '9') {
                        charstest[i] = chars[i] = 'A';                        
                        break;
                    } else if (c == 'H') {
                        charstest[i] = chars[i] = 'J';
                        break;
                    } else if (c == 'N') {
                        charstest[i] = chars[i] = 'P';
                        break;
                    } else if (c == 'Z') {
                        charstest[i] = chars[i] = 'a';
                        break;
                    } else if (c == 'k') {
                        charstest[i] = chars[i] = 'm';
                        break;
                    } else if (c == 'z') {
                        charstest[i] = chars[i] = '2';
                        // No break - let loop increment prior character.
                    } else {
                        charstest[i] = chars[i] = ++c;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            string result  = new string(chars);//expect S6c56bnXQiBjk9mqSYE7ykVQ7NzrRy
            return result;
        }
```

Here my code when i transform into c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "sha256.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    string input = "S6c56bnXQiBjk9mqSYE7ykVQ7NzrQA";
    string inputcharstest = input+"?";
    char * chars = new char[input.size() + 1];
    strcpy(chars, input.c_str());//convert input to char array
    char * charstest = new char[inputcharstest.size() + 1];
    strcpy(charstest, inputcharstest.c_str());// convert inputcharstest to char array
    string output = sha256(inputcharstest); //hash sha256 inputcharstest to check typo
    while (output[0] != '0') {
        for (int i = strlen(chars) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char c = chars[i];
            if (c == '9') {
                charstest[i] = chars[i] = 'A';
                break;
            }
            else if (c == 'H') {
                charstest[i] = chars[i] = 'J';
                break;
            }
            else if (c == 'N') {
                charstest[i] = chars[i] = 'P';
                break;
            }
            else if (c == 'Z') {
                charstest[i] = chars[i] = 'a';
                break;
            }
            else if (c == 'k') {
                charstest[i] = chars[i] = 'm';
                break;
            }
            else if (c == 'z') {
                charstest[i] = chars[i] = '2';              
            }
            else {
                charstest[i] = chars[i] = ++c;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    string result = string(chars); //expect S6c56bnXQiBjk9mqSYE7ykVQ7NzrRy
        cout << "input('" << input << "'):" << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

This is the result i expected
[image]

The code was stuck & return blank when i run it on console application, i debug & find out it was stuck in while loop forever. May i ask if there're any problem with this & how do i fix it?

Comment: You never modify `output[0]` in your loop. What do you expect?

Comment: @Ruks Since C++11, accessing one character past the end of an `std::string` is [guaranteed to return the null character](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at).

Comment: output wasn't empty, it contain the hash sha256 of the inputcharstest, i check the first character of it to see if it was '0'

Comment: If it's `0` the first time, it's going to be `0` the next time. And the next. And the next. And the...

Comment: @Nelfeal how can i modify it in loop, i'm new to c++

Comment: @Nelfeal i put sha256(inputcharstest) right in while loop & it declare error

Comment: @HuangLee `while (sha256(inputcharstest).at(0) != '0')`...

Comment: @Nelfeal oh nevermind, i confuse between chars & string, it been fix :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are changing the content of the string every time:

```
 char[] charstest = (keytotry + "?").ToCharArray();            
    while (Util.ComputeSha256(utf8.GetBytes(charstest))[0] != 0) {
```

`charstest` changes in every run through the loop, so the test in the `while` can terminate at some point. In the C++ code, however, you're not doing that:

```
string output = sha256(inputcharstest); //hash sha256 inputcharstest to check typo
while (output[0] != '0') {
```

Here, you're only doing the hash once before the loop, and then not again in the loop. The loop doesn't change `output` at all and neither does it `break` out of the `while`, so if `output[0] != '0'` is `true` the first time, it will always be true, thus the infinite loop.